# Is it possible to show preview extent box for PrintTask in ArcGIS 3.16 JavaScript API?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I have set up a map application using ArcGIS JavaScript API v3.16 and included functionality for exporting a map to PDF using the PrintTask.  Is there a way that I can use a button/checkbox to turn on an extent box to show on the map application of what portion of the map will show up on the export map output?  I have the PrintTask set up to preserve map scale - so extent is not preserved.  Usually the output of the PrintTask is less of an extent than that of the map application so I would like to let users be able to know what will be printed.

Comment: Take a look at this discussion on GeoNet that contains code to put in an extent box for the print output: https://geonet.esri.com/thread/174090

Comment: That looks like exactly what I am looking for, I will try that out.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See kenbuja's comment for answer.  See here: https://geonet.esri.com/thread/174090